# jetty 9 + JDK 8 + spring 4 Annotations

Tags: java-8, spring-annotations, spring-4, jetty-9

After upgrading to JDK 8 , the jetty 9 is no longer able to scan the spring annotations : I get the following error :

```
MultiException[java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file ApplicationInitializer.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file HibernateConfig.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file MailConfig.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file ServicesConfig.class, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file WebAppConfig.class]
at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations(AnnotationConfiguration.java:530)
at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:441)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:466)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:745)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:492)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:282)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:99)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
```

It was working fine when i used jdk 7 .

The annotations it tries to scan are spring framework 4 annotations something like :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.cityrentals.rentahouse")
@Import({ HibernateConfig.class, ServicesConfig.class, MailConfig.class })
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

The error occurs irrespective of  if the javaassist dependency is present or not

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
   <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
   <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
  </dependency>
```

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks
Suresh

Answer (score 9):

Because of the version differences between spring mvc Java (8) and the version of ASM bundled in Jetty, you have the kind of exceptions you have experienced.

You need to make the versions compatible with each other by downloading ASM 5.xx and replacing the following 2 files within the Jetty installation folder:

1. asm-4.x.jar with asm-5.xx.jar
2. asm-commons-4.x.jar with asm-commons-5.xx.jar

Comment: issue seems to be fixed in jetty-9.2.2 (maybe earlier)

Answer (score 3):

Using jetty-9.1.x, Java 8 and Spring 4 the answer by Ginger Head is correct. Just to supplement that answer:

If you are using the **jetty-runner** with version 9.1.x you may notice that it uses a bundled version of *asm* (bundled in the jar). To get it working with the bundled version I had to add the asm-jars on the *classpath*, before the jetty-runner-jar and then start jetty-runner without the -jar flag and instead point out the main class (*org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner*).

So, this **IS** working:

```
java -cp lib/asm-5.x.jar:lib/asm-commons-5.x.jar:lib/asm-tree-5.x.jar:lib/jetty-runner.jar org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner foo.war
```

The following is **NOT** working:

```
java -cp -jar lib/jetty-runner.jar foo.war
or
java -cp lib/asm-5.x.jar:lib/asm-commons-5.x.jar:lib/asm-tree-5.x.jar -jar lib/jetty-runner.jar foo.war
```

Comment: Quick update, this issue has now been resolved in later versions of Jetty (or more specifically in version 9.2.0.v20140526). The new version requires no special handling of the asm-jars for Java 8, Jetty 9 and Spring 4 - it should work out-of-the-box.